# particular solution of differential equation which $g(t)$ is dirac delta function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I want to find just the particular solution of following differential equation I will be thankful if anybody can help me.
$$
y^{(4)}+Ay''+By=\delta(x)
$$
[image]

Since $A$ and $B$ are varying parameters I cant use Laplace transform.

Comment: Are $A$ and $B$ parameters or functions? (Of $x$?)

Answer (score 0):

Take any linear differential operator $L$ of order $d$ with leading coefficient one.
To get a solution for $$L[y]=δ$$ you need a solution of $$L[y_0]=0$$ with initial conditions 
$$
y_0(0)=y_0'(0)=...=y_0^{(d-2)}(0)=0\text{ and } y_0^{(d-1)}(0)=\frac1{(d-1)!}
$$
Then 
$$
y=y_0u, \text{ where }u(x)={\bf 1}_{[0,\infty)}(x)
$$
is the unit ramp function, solves the original problem. Add homogeneous/complementary solutions as necessary.

---

Alternatively, set $y(x)=z(x)+\frac16x^3u(x)$, then
$$
y^{(4)}(x)+Ay''(x)+By(x)=z^{(4)}(x)+δ(x)+A(z''(x)+xu(x))+B(z(x)+\tfrac16x^3u(x))
$$
which gives a non-singular right side in the equation for $z$
$$
z^{(4)}(x)+Az''(x)+Bz(x)=-Axu(x)-\tfrac16Bx^3u(x).
$$